# What is the time complexity of this Java program?

Tags: time-complexity, java

Below is the code.

```
public static boolean twoPositive(int[] num) {
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < num.length ) {                          
        int j = i + 1
        while (j < num.length) {                        
            if (Math.min(num[i], num[j]) > 0)
                return true;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

From my own understanding, as there is a nested loop, this is of O(n^2), which is the upper bound. It also seems to me that the lower bound is of O(n^2), as regardless of the array, it still has to go through both loops. Is this reasoning correct?

Also, would this mean that every array has exactly the same performance? I know that if an array has two positive integers, it would return true and go through less operations that an array with no positive integers. However, both go through the inner loop, and as both have O(n^2), they have the same runtime.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Best case would be an array full of numbers greater than 0

Comment: Would the worst case be the following three things, an array with no positive numbers, an array with the first number positive, and the rest non-positive, and an array with the last number positive, but all the rest non-positive? Also, it seems to me that the lower bound would be omega(n) and the upper bound would be O(nlogn). O(n^2) is wrong.

Comment: Doesn't matter, those will all take the same amount of time

Comment: Why do you think the upper bound is O(nlogn) and O(n^2) is wrong?

Comment: Originally, I assumed that the upper bound was O(n^2). However, my professor marked this as wrong. Thus, I am figuring out other options and I genuinely confused. On second thought, I think that it is O(n), since the second while loop is conditional on the value being positive. Hence, it seems that that the two loops are distinct from each other.

Comment: Regarding the worst case scenarios, there is a list of options which include the following: An array with no positive numbers, An array with the first number positive, but all the rest non-positive, An array with the last number positive, but all the rest non-positive. An array with the first two numbers positive. An array with the first and last numbers positive, but all the rest non-positive. An array with the last two numbers positive, and doesn't matter, because every array has exactly the same performance. To me, all but array list with first two numbers positive contribute to worst case.

Comment: I think your professor is wrong if he thinks it's not O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound (worst - case senario) is when there are 1 or 0 positive numbers in the array because the algorithm will terminate only when i is equal to the number of elements of the array. In this case the time complexity is O(n^2) because there is a nested loop. So for i = 0 ther will be n-1 comparisons for i = 1 n-2 comparisons ... so the total comparisons will be $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2} = \frac{n^2}{2} - \frac{-n}{2}$$ which is O(n^2).

The lower bound (best - case senario) is when the first 2 elements in the array are positive numbers so the algorithm will terminate instantly because of the return statement. Since in that senario the algorithm will make only a constant amount of comparisons - no matter the length n of the array - the time complexity will be O(1).

Comment: This is not what is meant by lower bound complexity. It's not about picking certain types of cases for which complexity is lower; it's about finding a function that is a lower bound on the complexity of *all* cases.

Comment: There may be a misunderstanding. By lower bound you mean big omega notation (Ω(n)) or best case senario? Because if you mean the former then indeed O(n^2) Ω(n^2) and Θ(n^2). If you mean best case senario then O(1) is the correct time complexity. I am from Greece so i am not very familiar with the terminology.

Comment: Yes, and what qualifies as the best case scenario? Isn't it always O(1)?

Comment: No, it is not always the case that best case senario in every algorithm will be O(1). Quicksort for example has O(n logn) as best case senario. Linear search from the other hand - as well as the algorithm that you've posted - has O(1) as best case senario. Best case senario means what is the fastest way for an algorithm to run. In quicksort there is no chance to be faster than O(n logn) for example, no matter how you arrange the elements. Ω(n^2) is a lower bound of a function in general. But i am not sure what of the 2 are you looking for. Did it help you?

Comment: Not really. Isn't the best case scenario for a sorting algorithm that the input is already sorted? Than you can decide that in O(1). If the best case scenario is a specific kind of input for which the problem can be solved quickly, then I think we can always find a best case scenario that can be processed in O(1) time.

Comment: No you didn't get it. First of all how can you check if an array is sorted in O(1)???? If you can please provide the code. Secondly and most important you don't seem to underestand the concept of best case senario. It is not about trying to find the fastest way to solve the problem (and even if that was the case, still O(1) cannot be guaranteed at all as the sorting example shows), but trying to to find the fastest running time of the algorithm itself! Quicksort can never run in anything less than O(n logn). NEVER.

Comment: (I could post some links but there are countless sites that explain quicksort time complexity. Just google it and you'll find dozens of them). In fact if the array is sorted as you say quicksort does even worse O(n^2) which is the worst case for the algorithm! The basic point here is that you try to find how fast the algorithm can run in an ideal case not trying to find and combine other algorithms to solve the problem faster. I would suggest you to read some algorithm books to clear in your mind some concepts about algorithmic complexity.

Comment: You cannot decide that an array is sorted without looking at all items. You can sometimes decide that an array is not sorted by looking just at the first two items or at any two items.